# jQuery Custom AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an autocomplete suggestion for countries listed in my database. I managed to get the list and I am trying to bind click event for entries for each country. Although I believe this is the way to do it, code is **always using the last item's value and placing it to the input field**.

`Suggestions` is my autocomplete container and the text field that I want to update is the `box`.

```
$('#box').on('input', function (){
   var typedLocation = { 'location' : $(this).val() };
   var key;

   $.post( "/suggestions.php", typedLocation, function( data ) {

       $('#Suggestions').html('').show();
       for (key in data) {
            $('#Suggestions').append('<div id="suggest' + key + '" >' + data[key] + '</div>');

            $('#Suggestions').find('#suggest' + key).click(function (){
                $('#Suggestions').hide();
                $('#box').val(data[key]);
            });
       } 
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm too tired to write something good. But if you google JavaScript Closure issue you will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the variable for setting the value of input field, I have used `$(this).html()` in the click function.

Adopting it to Joe's example (as it seems more elegant):

```
var $elem = $('<div>' + data[key] + '</div>');

$elem.click(function () {
            $('#Suggestions').hide();
            $('#box').val($(this).html());
        });
$('#Suggestions').append($elem);
```